# property page inside property sheet paints incorrect background on windows 11

Tags: c++, winapi, desktop-application, wtl, windows-11

My standard win32 program overrides WM_CTLCOLORDLG to offer "dark mode" dialogs, returning a brush according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/wm-ctlcolordlg). The code works fine for all windows from 98 to 10.

For windows 11, although plain dialogs show with a dark background without problem, those **inside a property sheet** (again standard using PropertySheet API) don't paint correctly, as in this picture

[image: dark property page in w10 and w11]

notice that individual controls in the page paint correct dark backgrounds, but the property page dialog doesn't

The WM_CTLCOLORDLG handler is called, but the returned background brush is ignored in this case. Has anyone tried "custom" property pages in windows 11?

Comment: It seems an issue , I suggest you could post the issue to the [DC](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=62&entry=problem) for better help.

Comment: this forum you suggested is for visual studio problems, but this one looks like a windows 11 problem, are you sure it's the right way to go ahead?

Comment: Just because a username ends with MSFT does not mean they actually work for Microsoft. Asking here on SO is fine.

Comment: I found an easy way to patch this problem, manually paint the embedded dialog black during WM_ERASEBKGND